# Какие глаголы сочетаются со словом «линзы»?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Что мы делаем с линзами, одеваем, надеваем, вставляем? Предложение звучит так: Скажи ему, пусть...(контактные) линзы.Надо, чтобы он к ним привыкал.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем контексте - надевают, я думаю. Только не "одевают". 
"Вставляют"- безусловно правильно, но звучит как разовый вариант, а не как пожелание многократной и постоянной н**о**ски.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае напрашивается "наденет". "Вставит" звучит немного грубовато. Очки же надевают, значит и линзы можно.

Answer (score 1):

Линзы носят, надевают (на глаза; на роговицу - в мед. текстах), вставляют (в глаза - при акценте на действие, которое технически связано с установкой "вглубь", за веки). Одевать - разговорный вариант, в неформальной ситуации допустимый. В предложении о привыкании можно нейтрально выразиться: "пусть (немного) поносит".

Comment: *Одевать - разговорный вариант* - Нет, только не это.)))  Одевают Надежду, надевают одежду. И линзы. С "поносит" согласен, хотя со слуха тоже звучит плохо. ))

Comment: Сам я так не говорю, но вспомнил сейчас прошлогоднюю дискуссию о предметах одежды, в которой Вера меня примерами убедила, что в некоторых случаях такое отклонение от формальности допустимо.

Comment: Пусть опробует контактные линзы?

Comment: Это если он доброволец-испытатель :)